# how to display database field value in textbox in telerik report

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I want to display database field value from one of the dataset into header part of the telerik report. I have added a new textbox but I am not able to see any fields to be added into textbox in the expression window.

I have identified that when we set report datasource property, we can see the datasource fields in the textbox expression but if I add that, it messes up my report as I have set table datasource property.

I am new to telerik reports and I am using VS2012 to design reports.

Thanks,
Hardik

Comment: Look at this post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/textbox-display-value-from-second-datasource

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string companyName = dt.Rows[0]["Company Name"].ToString();

this.textBox1.Value = companyName;

// some code here..
```